# Im trying to web scrape Forbes business but when i request the url it doesn't give me the correct json data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im using python, my code:

```
import requests
import bs4
url = 'https://www.forbes.com/business'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

and this is what it returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="en_US" http-equiv="Content-Language"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
                        (function () {
                                function isValidUrl(toURL) {
                                        // Regex taken from welcome ad.
                                        return (toURL || '').match(/^(?:https?:?\/\/)?(?:[^.(){}\\\/]*)?\.?forbes\.com(?:\/|\?|$)/i);
                                }

                                function getUrlParameter(name) {
                                        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
                                        var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
                                        var results = regex.exec(location.search);
                                        return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
                                };

                                function consentIsSet(message) {
                                        console.log(message);
                                        var result = JSON.parse(message.data);
                                        if(result.message == "submit_preferences"){
                                                var toURL = getUrlParameter("toURL");
                                                if(!isValidUrl(toURL)){
                                                        toURL = "https://www.forbes.com/";
                                                }
                                                location.href=toURL;
                                        }
                                }

                                var apiObject = {
                                        PrivacyManagerAPI:
                                        {
                                                action: "getConsent",
                                                timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
                                                self: "forbes.com"
                                        }
                                };
                                var json = JSON.stringify(apiObject);
                                window.top.postMessage(json,"*");
                                window.addEventListener("message", consentIsSet, false);
                        })();
                </script>
</head>
<body><div id="teconsent">
<script async="async" crossorigin="" src="//consent.truste.com/notice?domain=forbes.com&amp;c=teconsent" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Im sure im doing something very obviously wrong or i need a header of some sort but im new to this and dont completely understand it, so i would appropriate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first steps you should do when you want to scrape a website is to see what happens when you switch off javascript. You can do this in chrome by inspecting the page and going to the settings (There are three dots). In this case doesn't look like javascript is being employed in great detail.

The other thing you should think about is whether there is a need for headers, cookies and parameters. In this case, you need to send the headers with the HTTP request.

```
headers = {
'authority': 'www.forbes.com',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36',
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cookie': 'client_id=4f023ae61ab633d8e7e2410a838a6ef93b8; notice_preferences=2:1a8b5228dd7ff0717196863a5d28ce6c; notice_gdpr_prefs=0,1,2:1a8b5228dd7ff0717196863a5d28ce6c; _cb_ls=1; _cb=DV5nM5D9GHBDCzpjkB; _ga=GA1.2.611301459.1592235761; __tbc=%7Bjzx%7DIFcj-ZhxuNCMjI4-mDfH1HGM-3PFKcN8Miwl1Jhx9eZNEmuQGlLmxXFL-9qM-F_OBO51AtKdJ3qgOfi3P9vM0qBHA3PyvmasSB5xaCbWibdU2meZrLoZ92gJ8xiw07mk3E9l5ifC0NcYbET3aSZxuA; xbc=%7Bjzx%7DGUDHEU3rvhv6-gySw5OY32YdbGDIZI_hJ7AHN4OvkbydVClZ3QNjNrlQVyHGl3ynSJzzGsKf0w3VfH3le6pYqMAfTQAzgDTJbUHa-cJS7p3ITwLt3PmPKKvsIVyFnHji; __gads=ID=a5ac1829fa387f90:T=1592235777:S=ALNI_MZfOqlh-TglrQCWbFNtjcjgFfkMGQ; _fbp=fb.1.1592235779290.60238202; __qca=P0-59264648-1592235777617; xdibx=N4Ig-mBGAeDGCuAnRIBcoAOGAuBnNAjAKwCcATGQMxEDsAHHQAyUkA0IGAbrAHbaHtc-VMXJVaDZmw6dcvfiPaIkAGzQgAFtmwZcqAPT6A7iYB0AMwD2iSAFNcp2JYC2-3AEts9.c.cBrW0sALwBDHncw.TJGaP1GADZ9Yn0eWyNYENxsFVsAWnhwrwATXNwQnNyQrERLTnLK3PMVdwxcy3Nc7A08p3cQdhVVdTdPb18A4LCIniiYxjjE5NT0zOy8gtGSsoqqjBq6lQamlraOrp7Ldx5SkIBPXFy9219bRFyckIBzeDz-kBU8IRSBRqPQmCwAL7sCAwJ6cNCgIp3YQAbVEIIkTAALDQALpQ8BQaC2Ti2PjCUDRBKUSgIkDw9AgWACEAKNHA8T0EiMEiUfGCOnM1CMdhs.kgFCMoUi1loFHioqCtAysUEoWgaWiuX4gnRMhYxiMOkMjUstnozl0ch0IjiilM5Va1DygmS03Cp0u9iKqWO2XO8Xqh0e.0uiEEmFwdw-kAhLHRLEkIodWyQEKwXJYrHxeK5SBEG2Z2A0EJFSCUMsJDMW0F0GhY4ggCFAA__; _chartbeat2=.1592235763483.1592235790833.1.CZMImKDrkr6iBB9QkcCHzJBoDWn8ZI.3',}
```

You can get access to this via inspecting the page by right clicking the page. Then clicking the doc part. You can copy the CURL(bash) cmd of the request and post it into curl.trillworks.com. This will be able to convert to python and give you nicely formatted headers.

### Code Example

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.forbes.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'client_id=4f023ae61ab633d8e7e2410a838a6ef93b8; notice_preferences=2:1a8b5228dd7ff0717196863a5d28ce6c; notice_gdpr_prefs=0,1,2:1a8b5228dd7ff0717196863a5d28ce6c; _cb_ls=1; _cb=DV5nM5D9GHBDCzpjkB; _ga=GA1.2.611301459.1592235761; __tbc=%7Bjzx%7DIFcj-ZhxuNCMjI4-mDfH1HGM-3PFKcN8Miwl1Jhx9eZNEmuQGlLmxXFL-9qM-F_OBO51AtKdJ3qgOfi3P9vM0qBHA3PyvmasSB5xaCbWibdU2meZrLoZ92gJ8xiw07mk3E9l5ifC0NcYbET3aSZxuA; xbc=%7Bjzx%7DGUDHEU3rvhv6-gySw5OY32YdbGDIZI_hJ7AHN4OvkbydVClZ3QNjNrlQVyHGl3ynSJzzGsKf0w3VfH3le6pYqMAfTQAzgDTJbUHa-cJS7p3ITwLt3PmPKKvsIVyFnHji; __gads=ID=a5ac1829fa387f90:T=1592235777:S=ALNI_MZfOqlh-TglrQCWbFNtjcjgFfkMGQ; _fbp=fb.1.1592235779290.60238202; __qca=P0-59264648-1592235777617; xdibx=N4Ig-mBGAeDGCuAnRIBcoAOGAuBnNAjAKwCcATGQMxEDsAHHQAyUkA0IGAbrAHbaHtc-VMXJVaDZmw6dcvfiPaIkAGzQgAFtmwZcqAPT6A7iYB0AMwD2iSAFNcp2JYC2-3AEts9.c.cBrW0sALwBDHncw.TJGaP1GADZ9Yn0eWyNYENxsFVsAWnhwrwATXNwQnNyQrERLTnLK3PMVdwxcy3Nc7A08p3cQdhVVdTdPb18A4LCIniiYxjjE5NT0zOy8gtGSsoqqjBq6lQamlraOrp7Ldx5SkIBPXFy9219bRFyckIBzeDz-kBU8IRSBRqPQmCwAL7sCAwJ6cNCgIp3YQAbVEIIkTAALDQALpQ8BQaC2Ti2PjCUDRBKUSgIkDw9AgWACEAKNHA8T0EiMEiUfGCOnM1CMdhs.kgFCMoUi1loFHioqCtAysUEoWgaWiuX4gnRMhYxiMOkMjUstnozl0ch0IjiilM5Va1DygmS03Cp0u9iKqWO2XO8Xqh0e.0uiEEmFwdw-kAhLHRLEkIodWyQEKwXJYrHxeK5SBEG2Z2A0EJFSCUMsJDMW0F0GhY4ggCFAA__; _chartbeat2=.1592235763483.1592235790833.1.CZMImKDrkr6iBB9QkcCHzJBoDWn8ZI.3',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.forbes.com/business/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Also remember response.content is for binary, response.text is for text. With web scraping HTML you almost always wants response.text